# Hama wireless USB Stick 54 disconnects after 5-10 minutes, power management being turned off

Tags: wireless, usb, disconnect

I am having troubles with setting up a Hama wireless USB Stick 54 connected to my aged computer. This is what happens:

- After booting, the network connection is established and works nicely
- About five minutes later, the connection is lost, even while using the network connection (e.g. surfing the internet or accessing LAN)
- I only can re-establish the connection by disconnecting the stick from the usb port and reconnecting it physically. But even then, the connection gets lost after only about one minute.

I did use the Hama wireless stick without any problems on the same computer with Win XP before.

This is what I have tried to fix or diagnose the problem:

- I bought a 2m usb extension cable to be able to place the usb stick in a better spot
- I found https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntuusers.de%2FWLAN%2FKarten%2FHama%2F, so I blacklisted the module rt2500usb

  - first attempt:

```
echo "blacklist rt2500usb" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-Hama.conf
```

- - second attempt:

```
echo "blacklist rt2500usb" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

- I found
  https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.ubuntuusers.de%2FWLAN%2F

  - I turned off power management:

```
sudo sed -i "s/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/g" /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

- - I moved the usb devices around:

    1. I got an old powered usb hub out and connected the Hama stick through this one
    2. I connected the Hama stick directly as the only device to a double usb
  - There is a diagnostic script mentioned, but I couldn’t fully figure it out. This is the output I got (with the connection lost):

```
wpa_supplicant v2.4
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Initializing interface 'wlx000e2efc752f' conf 'wpa_supplicant.tmp' driver 'wext' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
ctrl_interface='/var/run/wpa_supplicant'
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=1
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='XXX-20-15'
WEXT: cfg80211-based driver detected
wext: interface wlx000e2efc752f phy: phy0
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
Could not set interface wlx000e2efc752f flags (UP): Operation not permitted
WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlx000e2efc752f' UP
wlx000e2efc752f: Failed to initialize driver interface
Failed to add interface wlx000e2efc752f
wlx000e2efc752f: Cancelling scan request
wlx000e2efc752f: Cancelling authentication timeout
```

- Eventually, I found this: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)

  - I produced an output of the wireless-info script while the network was working nicely and another one after loss of the connection

    1. The first can be found here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5MZS8drpJN/
    2. The second can be found here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fVfGcrx8f9/
  - I compared the outputs. These are (in my opinion) the main differences:

    1. With connection:

```
wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XXX-20-15"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'XXX-20-15' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Link Quality=36/70  Signal level=-74 dBm
```

- - 2. After loss of connection:

```
wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"XXX-20-15"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'XXX-20-15' [AN1]>   
          Bit Rate=36 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Link Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
...
wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning : Device or resource busy
```

- - 3. I wonder especially about the AC1 and AN1, but I couldn’t find any helpful information
  - I have also created a script output after I ran the diagnostic script mentioned above earlier (https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fforum.ubuntuusers.de%2Ftopic%2Fherstellung-der-wlan-verbindung-dauert-sehr-la%2F%23post-4040812)

    1. It can be found here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2yHk2R2ZNr/
    2. Maybe it helps investigating as well

This all said, I’d appreciate some help in getting the Hama wireless stick working.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost embarressed to answer my own question. However, the issue has been solved by accident.

The accident was that the computer didn't want to start anymore at all. Eventually, I got it up and running again, but pausing right at BIOS loading time. It complained about overclocking. Since I got this computer second hand, I actually never looked into the BIOS.

Nevertheless, I had two options - either F1 for entering BIOS setup or F2 for resetting the BIOS to standard. So, I took the easy way (F2), since I didn't need any special BIOS settings.

To my joy, the computer started nicely. I re-attached all the devices and ... suprise ... the wireless network kept running and running and running. No more disconnections so far. I am a happy camper.

I have to assume that some BIOS setting actually caused the USB ports to safe power and shut down or something. I don't know, I don't understand and currently I don't care. I just enjoy.